# django : create table form when selecting multiple rows

Tags: django, forms, datatable

I need to create a pretty straight forward form with Django but seems to be unable to find the proper tool for it, maybe because of the lack of vocabulary on what I want :

I have a table of n rows (n varies), each row represents a database object. I want to put a checkbox in front left of each row to be able to select multiple rows and apply an action placed in a multiplechoice widget at the top.

I thought about "serialize" a deleteview with formset but anyway I don't know how to add extra actions (apart from delete).

Any valuable information on direction to take would be welcome, thanks.

Comment: Oh, so it's you that the whole world is always talking about, John Doe :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [Django Tables 2](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Try like this:

#### Define Table:

```
import django_tables2 as tables


class YourTable(tables.Table):
    selection = tables.CheckBoxColumn(accessor='pk')  # Override here to show checkbox 
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
```

#### Use table in View:

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        table = YourTable(YourModel.objects.all())
        return render(request, 'template.html', context={'table': table})
```

#### Template

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <select name="action_options">
        <option value="delete">Delete</option>
        <option value="hard_delete">Hard Delete</option>
    </select> 

    {% load render_table from django_tables2 %}  // loading template tag
    {% render_table table %}  // catching context as table from view

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete">
</form>
```

#### Update View to Handle Post Request

```
def some_view(request):
    ...
    if request.method == "POST":
        pks = request.POST.getlist("selection")  # handle selection from table
        action = request.POST.get('action_options')
        selected_objects = YourModel.objects.filter(pk__in=pks)
        if action == 'delete':
            selected_objects.delete()
        # Rest of your Logic
```