# Showing model entries as a form in a table

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model which has data that i need to show to a user in the form of a table. The user can select rows in the table and then proceed to the next page with only those items.

I think the way to do this with django is to crate a table where every row is a form, when a user clicks on a row it updates the status of that entry in the table to be "Selected" and when the user proceeds to next page, a new queryset with only entries with a status of "Selected" are shown.

Does this make sense? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: you can use [django table 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53492229/11225821) to get multiple select handle in a table

Comment: That makes sense, it's the exact way that the admin works. If I were you I would use a [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField) for the first form and use a [form wizard](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html) to pass values from one step to another